# authenticating using a text file in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i have a auth.txt file that contains a username and password. my aim is to use this file to see if the user entered a valid username and password before proceeding to the next menu. 
eg. auth.txt contains user \n pass. when they select a menu it asks them for a logon. if they enter incorrectly it does nothing. each password and usrname is stored in the auth.txt file.
i tried using the following code but got nothing. please help and thanks in advance.

```
if(getline(inauth, line)){ 

    if(line==user&& line==password){ 
    //your in

    }else cout<<"bye";
    }
```

Comment: line is user and password at the same time? That's what your code implies.

Comment: You really don't want to store users' passwords. Store a hash of the password, and when they enter a new one, hash it the same way to see if you get the same result. You want a cryptographic hash for this (e.g., SHA-256).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only reading one line and then you're trying to compare to both "user" and "password". That certainly can't work. You'll need to call getline twice. Don't forget to check for errors, you can never be too safe with user authentication. Try something like this:

```
ifstream inauth("Secret password herein.txt");

if (inauth) {
    string usr, psw;

    if (getline(inauth, usr) && getline(inauth, psw) {
        if (usr == user && psw == password) {
            cout << "Phew, everything's fine.";
        } else {
            cout << "Wrong password/username.";
        }
    } else {
        cout << "I guess somebody opened the file in notepad and messed it up."
    }
} else {
    cout << "Can't open file, sorry.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a VC++ developer, but this should be the right logic for what you want to accomplish.

```
// keep looping while we read lines
while (getline(inauth, line)) 
{
    // valid user
    if (line == user) 
    {
        // read the next line
        if (getline(inauth, line2))
        {
            if (line2 == password)
            {
                // successfully authenticated
                cout << "Success!";
            } 
            else 
            {
                // valid user, invalid password
                // break out of the while loop
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your username and password are stored in the same line delimited by, say a whitespace then, you'll have to do

```
#include <sstream>

string line, username, password;
istringstream instream;
while (getline(inauth, line))
{
    // extract username and password from line using stringstream
    instream.clear();
    instream.str(line);
    instream >> username >> password;
    // do something here
}
```